# Export parts of image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have an image containing some black letters.
I'm trying to export the letters one by one. My code works fine until the image contains more than one line.

The image looks like this:

[image]

Please note that this image has basically "normal" letters. At some points they will be italic and bent in strange ways.

The images that show up in the folder `SplitedImages`:

[image]

My code for exporting:

```
foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "\\CaptchaImages"))
{
    RawCaptcha = new ImageData(MakeGrayscale3(new Bitmap(s), 160));
    MakeGrayscale3(new Bitmap(s), 160).Save(Application.StartupPath + "StackOverFlow.png");
    // remove the blue pixels
    Filter.ReplaceSimilarColor(ref RawCaptcha, Color.FromArgb(98, 139, 218), Color.FromArgb(226, 226, 226), 70);
    // darken the dark black pixels
    Filter.ReplaceSimilarColor(ref RawCaptcha, Color.FromArgb(25, 32, 16), Color.Black, 50);
    // convert to black and white
    Filter.BlackAndWhite(ref RawCaptcha, 20);

    /* --------------- Buchstaben trennen -------------------------------------------- */
    // wir testen jede Spalte
    bool[] VertikaleLinien = new bool[RawCaptcha.Width];
    // jede Spalte durchlaufen
    for (Int32 column = 0; column < RawCaptcha.Width; column++)
    {
        // erst denken wir, dass wir eine Linie zeichnen können
        bool blank = true;
        // dann schauen wir mal, ob wir an schwarzen Pixeln anecken
        for (Int32 row = 0; row < RawCaptcha.Height; row++)
        {
            if (RawCaptcha.GetPixel(column, row) == Color.Black)
            {
                // ups ein schwarzer Pixel => hier ist ein Buchstabe
                blank = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // alle Pixel weiß
        if (blank)
        {
            // wir merken uns, dass wir die Linie zeichnen können
            VertikaleLinien[column] = true;
            // und Linie zeichnen
            for (int row = 0; row < RawCaptcha.Height; row++)
                RawCaptcha.SetPixel(column, row, Color.FromArgb(225, 225, 225));
        }
        else
        {
            // Linie kann nicht gezeichnet werden
            VertikaleLinien[column] = false;
        }
    }

    List<Bitmap> Letters = new List<Bitmap>();

    bool open = false;          // = false --> nor red area
    int left = 0, width = 0;    // remember position
    for (Int32 column = 0; column < RawCaptcha.Width; column++)
    {
        // not in gray area?
        if (!VertikaleLinien[column])
        {
            if (open == false)
            {
                // new start of letter
                left = column;
                // draw green vertical line
                for (int row = 0; row < RawCaptcha.Height; row++)
                    RawCaptcha.SetPixel(column - 1, row, Color.Green);
            }
            open = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (open == true)
            {
                // end of current letter
                width = column - left - 1;
                if (width > 1)
                {
                    Letters.Add(RawCaptcha.GetBitmap(left, 0, width, RawCaptcha.Height - 3));
                    // draw blue vertical line
                    for (int row = 0; row < RawCaptcha.Height; row++)
                        RawCaptcha.SetPixel(column + 1, row, Color.Blue);
                    left = column;
                    open = false;
                }

            }

        }
    }

    foreach (Bitmap bmpp in Letters)
    {
        bmpp.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\SplitedImages\\" + GetFileName(Application.StartupPath + "\\SplitedImages") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
    filesToDelete.Add(s);
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered splitting horizontally before doing the vertical splits?

Comment: @GrawCube Yes, wont work properly if the pixels are too close or if the letters on the image is too high up compared to the rest